# Jquery validation BIC IBAN in asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, iban

I'm using the latest version of the Jquery Validation plugin which has support for validating BIC and IBAN numbers. This is part of the additional methods js which I've included and is working fine for validating IBANs, however, it fails when validating BICs. When I say fails I mean the call to validate doesn't work, not that it's incorrectly validating the BIC sequence.

Here's my code:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtBIC" CssClass="donBic" AutoComplete="off"></asp:TextBox>
```

And here's my Jquery

```
 $('.donBic').rules('add', {
     bic: true
  });
```

I have to presume the 'bic' usage isn't the correct way to call that form of validation, yet this code works perfectly well for validating IBANS:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtIBAN" CssClass="donIban" AutoComplete="off"></asp:TextBox>

  $('.donIban').rules('add', {
     iban: true
   });
```

Does anyone know the correct way to call BIC validation?

[BIC / IBAN code in github](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/commit/ed51405d847e18765d7b3872164a261fb3848b72)

Comment: If it works for iban it should work for bic. The jQuery validation plugin has a [debug mode](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate) that displays errors on the console, maybe you can use it to get more information

Comment: I've put it into debug mode and am getting this error: Cannot call method 'call' of undefined.

Comment: Ok, from looking at the code in the additional methods it looks like BIC validation has been removed, I've no idea why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for your comment (@Full Time Skeleton) that there's no BIC method, here's how you can add it:

Add this to your onReady event handler:

```
$.validator.addMethod("bic", function(value, element){
    return this.optional( element ) || /^([A-Z]{6}[A-Z2-9]{1}[A-NP-Z1-2]{1})(X{3}|[A-WY-Z0-9]{1}[A-Z0-9]{2})?$/.test( value );
}, "Please specify a valid BIC code");
```

You can find the documentation page for addMethod [here](http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod)

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, the BIC validation was removed from the latest version of the additional methods. I copied it in from the link provided in my question and it appears to work.